# Accessing private members when implementing in a .cpp file

Tags: c++, stack, private-members

I'm trying to implement code for a .h file in a .cpp file. This is the header file:

```
class ProcessOrders
{
public: 
    double process_shipment(int q, double c);
    double process_order(int q);
private:
    std::stack<Inventory> Inventory_on_hand;    // keep track of inventory on hand
    std::stack<Order> orders_to_be_filled;      // keep track of orders
};
```

The problem is that the functions process_shipment and process_order require the ability to push things onto the private stacks, but I get an "unable to resolve identifier" error if I try to refer to them in the .cpp file.

This is probably really obvious, but how do I get access to the private members while implementing the public ones in the .cpp file? I can't modify the header file.

Comment: Can you please create [mcve].

Comment: In my case the error was caused because the methods were first declared in a superclass, and they were `private` when they should have been `protected`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you implement member functions outside of their class you need to prefix all member functions' names with `ClassName::`.

Doing that enables you to just access every private variable with their respective name.

Also do not forget to `#include` your header file of your class at the top of your `.cpp` file.

```
double ProcessOrders::process_shipment(int q, double c)
{ /*...*/ Inventory_on_hand. //... }
double ProcessOrders::process_order(int q)
{ /*...*/ }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access them in the .cpp for the class. Header files contain declaration while .cpp files have definition.

In the above code, both stacks are private which means they can be only accessed within the functions of the same class. So when you will define process_shipment in your .cpp file, you can push anything in the stack.

You can access orders_to_be_filled stack within the

```
double ProcessOrders::process_shipment(int q, double c)
```

using the code

```
this.orders_to_be_filled;
```